# php zip adding non selected files

Tags: php, zip

I had a set of files in a folder. from this few will select and adding to zip. But it adding non selected files also.

The sample file names are

```
EXPLORER_TRM_FDM_147461_B_280.pdf, 
EXPLORER_TRM_FDM_147463_B_130.txt, 
EXPLORER_TRM_FDM_147470_B_130.pdf,
```

From this I am selecting only second one but all are coming.

my function is

```
public function zipFilesDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");     
    }
    foreach($file_names as $files){
        $zip->addFile($file_path.strtolower($files),$files);        
    }
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile("$archive_file_name");
    exit;   
}
```

`$file_names` contain only

```
EXPLORER_TRM_FDM_147463_B_130.txt
```

but the other two also adding into zip. where I am wrong?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to checking count of `$file_names` content

Comment: this already tried. not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? It should return content of `$file_names` and you should check that is contain more than one file?

Comment: Do you clean/delete zip file on every run?

Comment: I understand the issue. the zip file created in server and next time it loading from cache. I deleted the created zip file after download. So the issue solved. Thanks for the comments